# Find 00 in the array containing 0 and 00

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, collections

## example

```
$member = 0 => [
               "username" => '0'
              ]
          1 => [
               "username" => '00'
          ];

$collection = collect($member);

$dataUSER = $collection->where('username','00')->first();
```

but i got data username 0 ,i want username 00

How can i where in collection

Comment: i think you should initialize proper array first.

Comment: `0` and `00` are exactly the same number.

Comment: Did either of the below solutions solve your problem or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

very simple, use strict operator I tested it to be sure.

```php
$dataUSER = $collection->where('username', '===','00')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you could use [whereStrict()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-whereinstrict) instead of [where()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-where):

```
 $dataUSER = $collection->whereStrict('username', '00')->first();
```